# How to create a xml style to alternate rowbackground color ever 2 rows if column is false

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, styles

[Alternating Colors on Rows Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ9Lw.png)

Hi Everyone, I wanted to know if there was someone who can help me put things together. I'm trying to create a **style** for my datagrid. I want the table rows to act the way I've represented them to act in the image. So basically I have a column that is a bool. When it's true I want to row to be a certain color. Then when it's not false I want the colors alternating every 2 rows until it encounters another row where the bool is true.

I've been messing with triggers, multitdatatriggers, but still no luck.

Comment: Dude this is one of those where a first page on the google machine reveals even step-by-step videos how to. Give it a shot first and come back with code when you run into a more specific issue. :)

Comment: If your so sure can you please provide me with a link ? Cause I can't find one.

Comment: Sure thing, [first page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blx4DL9j39U) or there's other tutorials for the same scenario in different ways. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for that video I ended up finding an easier way. In my mind I was over complicating the thing I wanted to do. I'll post the answer up.

Answer (score 0):

Style in App.xml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="3">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isLeague}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Grid on MyControl.xaml

```
<DataGrid Name="DG1" AlternationCount="4">
```